# Linking to the main folder from any where

Tags: php

I want to know the best way to link back to my main folder both in my local server and when uploaded to my main server because I don't want to pass through the stress of editing my code all over again when I want to upload it and I want to achieve this through `php`.

I know the `/` would work but it only works when I echo it out, if I did something like this  `include '/connect.php'`  I get this error in my main server:

> Warning: include(/tutorials/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/stephens/public_html/kings/home.php

I also get an error in my local server saying:

> Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\projects\tutorials) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\home.php.

I tried this also `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but Its not working in my main server, only for the local server.

I also used `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` but It's not working also.

Please does anyone have a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Try using `__DIR__`, but *permission denied* and *no such file found* errors are different. The one was found but had wrong permissions so this wouldn't fix that.

Comment: Indeed. You will find your answer in the answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory